# Login with PHP doesn´t show any html code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I´ve a problem a login, the page doesn´t show anything. This is the code:

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require 'connect_db.php';
/* start the session */
session_start();
conectar();
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
// counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1)
{
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   $_SESSION['start'] = time();
   $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (10 * 60) ; 
   echo "<body><p>Welcome! </p></body>";
}
else
{
    echo "Mail or password not correct.";
    echo "<a href='teacher.html'>Try again</a>";
}
//$conexion->close();
?>
```

The **HTML** calling this code is:

```
      <form action= "php/login_profesores.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validacion()">
          <label>Mail</label>
          <input type="text" class="" id="inputMail"></input></br></br>
          <label>DNI</label>
          <input type="password" id="inputDNI"></input></br>
          <input name="Enviar" type="submit" class="submit" value="Send" /></input></br>
      </form>
```

validación() is the javascript code what works, but the problem is that php doesn´t show any page when the user logins in the system. The DB is well-configured and teacher´s table exists.

**connect_db**

```
<?php
function conectar()
{
define('DB_SERVER','http://**/');
define('DB_NAME','**');
define('DB_USER','**');
define('DB_PASS','**');
$conexion=new mysqli();
$conexion->connect('DB_SERVER','DB_USER','DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME');
$error=$conexion->connect_error;  //Tambien vale connect_error
echo $error;
}
?>
```

Comment: please share the code of `connect_db.php` file also...
or try to write `session_start();` before `require 'connect_db.php';`

Comment: Now updated the code

Comment: I´ve tried the connexion and it throws an error 2002 what says: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: Have you enabled PHP error logs on your server?

Comment: Yes, first error is: `PHP Warning:  mysqli::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Answer (score 4):

You must have name attribute in your input fields if you want to pass the value using POST, GET or any other method.

```
<input type="text" class="" name="email" id="inputMail"></input></br></br>
<label>DNI</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="inputDNI"></input></br>
```

Comment: Post is written in form, isn´t enough? I´ve tried the connexion and it throws an error 2002 what says: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: I think there is some issue in your connect_db.php file. Is that generating any error?

Comment: No, I only see it if I write the line `echo $error`

Answer (score 0):

In the form you are specifing input types but you are not specifying names for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MySQL_` procedural in your PHP page but you're using MySQLi_ Object Orientated in your connection page.

Update everything to `MySQLi` (object orientated). `MySQL_` is now deprecated and no longer supported and should not be used.

You should also check with your SQL that it allows access from the IP address your page is trying to access it from. If they are on the same server then you should replace your SQL database connection address with `localhost` .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works! I had to write the name of server without http:// and I had another problem mixing mysql and mysqli because it is not correct.